# Batch- command prompt doesn't do math

Tags: batch-file, math, cmd

I'm trying to make a Batch RPG game, and I'm working on a battle system.

Here is the code:

```
:Explore
cls
if %lvl% EQU 1 %random% %%5 +1
if %lvl% EQU 2 %random% %%5 +1
if %lvl% EQU 3 %random% %%5 +1
if %lvl% EQU 4 %random% %%5 +1
if %lvl% EQU 5 %random% %%5 +1
if %random% EQU 1 goto Bear
if %random% EQU 2 goto Wolf
if %random% EQU 3 goto Foot Soldier
if %random% EQU 4 goto Cannibal
if %random% EQU 5 goto Tiger

::Enemies

:Bear
set enemyname=Bear
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
set enemyhp=%random% %%50 +10
goto Battle

:Wolf
set enemyname=Wolf
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
set enemyhp=%random% %%25 +5
goto Battle

:Foot Soldier
set enemyname=Foot Soldier
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
set enemyhp=%random% %%25 +5
goto Battle

:Cannibal
set enemyname=Cannibal
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
set enemyhp=%random% %%25 +5
goto Battle

:Tiger
set enemyname=Tiger
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
set enemyhp=%random% %%30 +1
goto Battle

:Battle
cls
echo A level %enemylvl% %enemyname% (%enemyhp% HP) approaches! 
echo What will you do?
echo.
echo 1-Fight
echo 2-Run
echo.
set /p wwyd="Enter selection here:"
if %wwyd%==1 goto Fight
if %wwyd%==2 goto Run
```

When I run the program, instead of displaying the enemy variables (HP, name, lvl) it displays them with the math not done. For example, it shows "A Level 31244 /5 +1 Bear (11071 /50 +10 HP) approaches. What will you do?"

What is wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set /?` claims, you need `/a` to do arithmetic.

So as an example your line:

```
set enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
```

should be:

```
set /a enemylvl=%random% %%5 +1
```

Comment: Thanks again Stephan! I will probably have more questions in the future. Any resources (besides Youtube) for learning Batch?

Comment: *Windows NT Shell Scripting*, a book by Tim Hill.  The batch language hasn't changed very much since Windows NT, so it's still a good book for you to buy.